# Implementing locks

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

Some doubts when reading the operating system material of [implementing locks](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eouster/cgi-bin/cs140-winter13/lecture.php?topic=lockImpl)

```
struct lock {
    int locked;
    struct queue q;
    int sync;         /* Normally 0. */
};

void lock_acquire(struct lock *l) {
    intr_disable();
    while (swap(&l->sync, 1) != 0) {
        /* Do nothing */
    }
    if (!l->locked) {
        l->locked = 1;
        l->sync = 0;
    } else {
        queue_add(&l->q, thread_current());
        thread_block(&l->sync);
    }
    intr_enable();
}

void lock_release(struct lock *l) {
    intr_disable();
    while (swap(&l->sync, 1) != 0) {
        /* Do nothing */
    }
    if (queue_empty(&l->q) {
        l->locked = 0;
    } else {
        thread_unblock(queue_remove(&l->q));
    }
    l->sync = 0;
    intr_enable();
}
```

What is the purpose of `sync`?

Comment: Yes, queues in general are FIFO data structures, and that is what it seems to be from the code snippet you posted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My gut feeling is that the solutions are all broken. For a lock working correctly the lock_acquire needs to have acquire semantics and the lock_release needs to have release semantics. This way the loads/stores inside the critical section can't move outside of the critical section + you have a happens before edge between a lock release and a subsequent lock acquire on the same lock.

If you take a look at the spinning version:

```
struct lock {
   int locked;
};

void lock_acquire(struct lock *l) {
    while (swap(&l->locked, 1)) {
        /* Do nothing */
    }
}

void lock_release(struct lock *l) {
     l->locked = 0;
}
```

The assignment of locked=0 is just an ordinary store. This means that it can be reordered with other loads and stores before it + it doesn't provide a happens before edge.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that 'sync' is a way for the thread to let the OS know that the lock is in use since bot "lock" and "unlock" waits for 'sync" value to be changed before proceeding.

(It's a bit peculiar that interrupts are disabled before checking the 'sync' value)